# Changing Style Sheet of the whole window when CheckBox is checked

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

So I have this GUI and I'm trying to change the Style Sheet of it whenever the checkbox is checked. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
style_sheet = "#Form{background-color: rgb(255,255,255);}"
inverted_ss = "#Form{background-color: rgb(0,0,0);}"


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(698, 453)
        Form.setStyleSheet(style_sheet)

        #some design preferences here, including frame_19 and horizontalLayout_5 as seen below

        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.frame_19)
        self.checkBox.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.checkBox.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.checkBox.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.checkBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(29, 25))
        self.checkBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(29, 50))
        self.checkBox.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(25, 25))
        self.checkBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.checkBox.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.checkBox.setText("")
        self.checkBox.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(21, 21))
        self.checkBox.setCheckable(True)
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.mode_change)
        self.checkBox.setTristate(False)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.checkBox)

        #some more design preferences here

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "App"))

    def mode_change(self, state):
        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            Form.setStyleSheet(inverted)
        else:
            Form.setStyleSheet(style_sheet)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is, it gives me a warning: "Unresolved reference: 'Form' ". Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: Please show the complete error or provide re-producible code.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer The IDE I'm using (PyCharm) shows Form as a warning, that states exactly as I wrote above: "Unresolved reference: 'Form' ". When running the script, the app opens, but when I click on the checkbox, it crashes and shows the message "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)"

Comment: @MauriceMeyer the code is not reproducible, but the problem is clear: there's no reference to `Form` in the scope of `mode_change()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `Form` is only used as a **local** variable, used as argument of both `setupUi` and `retranslateUi` functions. Since there's no such argument in your `mode_change` function, python crashes as that reference does not exists in the function scope.

A possible solution would be to connect using a lambda that also returns the `Form` instance to the method:

```
        # ...
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(lambda state: self.mode_change(Form, state))
        # ...

    def mode_change(self, Form, state):
        # ...
```

Besides that, there's a more *conceptual* problem with your code, and it's that you're trying to edit a file generated with `pyuic` (or trying to mimic its behavior), which is something that should *never* be done. To correctly use those files, you only need to *import* them, and use one of the methods suggested in the official documentation about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

The most common and easy method is the *multiple inheritance* approach, for which you subclass from both the widget class *and* the pyuic class. In order to use the following code, regenerate the python file using `pyuic` and name it `ui_Form.py`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from ui_Form import Ui_Form

style_sheet = "#Form{background-color: rgb(255,255,255);}"
inverted_ss = "#Form{background-color: rgb(0,0,0);}"

class MyForm(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.mode_change)

    def mode_change(self, state):
        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.setStyleSheet(inverted)
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet(style_sheet)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myForm = MyForm()
    myForm.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your answer helped! Just a problem, if I have an image as the background in the style sheet (so like ss = "#Form{background-image: path-to-image;}"), it won't show. Should I change the #Form into something else?

Comment: [After your edit] Both work, I'm gonna use the "lambda state" solution as it works with everything I've programmed until now. Thank you so much, helped me a lot

Comment: 1) as explained in the [stylesheet reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html), all paths have to used with the `url()` syntax: `background-image: url(path-to-image);`. 2) I strongly suggest you to revise your whole project and use the suggested method, as you'll end up with lots of problems both with signal connections and whenever you'll need to change any of the UI files you created; it will take some time, but that's the only downside, as all you will get from that are only *lots* of benefits.

Comment: 1) I mean yeah, I know how that should be, but it doesn't work. 2) My project has like 32 form classes like the one in the example, it just might be too late for a change. And the fact that it works like this is more than I could have asked for. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I know this should be a different question, but is there any way to make that change of style sheet affect multiple windows? (Like if I have 3 opened, to affect every single one of them)

Comment: 1) paths must be relative (`...: url(image.png);` with the path relative to those of the *running* script), absolute (`...: url(/path/to/image.png);`) or set using Qt resources (`...: url(:/images/image.png);` assuming a .qrc resource file is created with Designer, it's been converted with `pyrcc` and imported in the main script. 2) I know the feeling, and I know you'll probably keep using your current approach, just keep in mind for the future.

Comment: 3) stylesheets can be applied from parent widgets and the QApplication instance using selectors (consult the [syntax documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html)). Normally using the subclass name is the preferred choice, but since you're not using subclasses (and this is a further reason for not modifying pyuic files) the only way is to use the `objectName` set in the `setupUi`; change those names to unique identifiers for each window/form and then use `app.setStyleSheet('SomeForm, AnotherForm { ... }')` when you want to use the same css for `SomeForm` and `AnotherForm`.

Comment: For the future, I'll probably change, thank you for your advice. And I think I found a way to change the stylesheet for 2 windows at the same time, It should be enough as I'll just close the others, smart/lazy but it gets the job done